# HEX query automation

Tags: haxe, zabbix

I have a control bord installed on a remote digital signage totem.
The card is connected via RS232 to an IP adapter which I can connect remotely.

I need to send it HEX commands every hour, get the answers and act according to them
(for example the command for what is the door status is: "AE 04 04 0A" and the answer is:   "{EF}{04}{04}{01}" the last digit is 1=open 0=closed)

I would like to take the answers and get them on my Zabbix monitor system for alerts, like if the door is open or the temp is high.

can you give me a direction to a platform that can run this kind of automation?

Answer (score 0):

It's surely doable, but it depends on the details of "IP adapter which I can connect remotely":

- is it an http gateway where you post your authentication and commands? Then use an `http item`
- is it a simple socket with no auth, just ip->rs232? Then a simple telnet/nc script called via zabbix with a `system.run` is the way to go
- is the interaction more complex? I.e: telnet, then authenticate, then subcommand1 and so on? A `system.run` as well, but to call a more complex script like expect or pexpect

In the simplest case, assuming a socket on host 1.2.3.4 and port 23 that just accepts input:

```
echo 'AE 04 04 0A' | nc -N 1.2.3.4 23 | perl -lne 'print $1 if /(?:{\w\w}){3}{(\w\w)}/'
```

This will send the hex command `AE 04 04 0A` to the device, then print the fourth portion of the result: so if the result string is `{EF}{04}{04}{01}`, the command will return `01`